# Computing slightly oscillatory series to high precision?

Tags: convergence, extrapolation

Suppose I have the following interesting function:
$$ f(x) = \sum_{k\geq1} \frac{\cos k x}{k^2(2-\cos kx)}. $$
It has some unpleasant properties, like its derivative not being continous at  rational multiples of $\pi$. I suspect a closed form does not exist.

I can compute it by computing partial sums and using Richardson extrapolation, but the problem is that it is too slow to compute the function to a good number of decimal digits (100 would be nice, for example).

Is there a method that can handle this function better?

Here's a plot of $f'(\pi x)$ with some artifacts:

[image: Function's derivative, $f'(\pi x)$]

Comment: Maybe you can use the fact that $cos(kx) = T_k(x)$, where $T_k(x)$ is a Chebyshev polynomial.  Then the summation starts to look like a series of rational polynomials.  Then if you can turn the series in to a rational polynomial in a Chebyshev basis, it would allow a very efficient way to sum it up.  If you aren't familiar with Chebyshev polynomials and basis, the Numerical Recipes in C has a good primer, as well as this: http://www2.maths.ox.ac.uk/chebfun/ATAP/ATAPfirst6chapters.pdf

Comment: er, that should say $cos(kx) = T_k(cos(x))$

Comment: @JayLemmon Thanks you for that link. I'll have a look and see if it helps.

Comment: I'm joining this party a bit late, but have you tried using Padé approximants, i.e. the $\varepsilon$-Algorithm instead of Richardson extrapolation?

Comment: By analogy with the case of highly oscillatory integrals, I don't think you'll be able to do a good job without some knowledge of the separation between oscillatory and nonoscillatory parts.  If you have such a separation, the Fourier series answer gives you easy exponential convergence.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If analytic techniques are disallowed but the periodic structure is known, here is one approach.  Let
$$g(x) = \frac{\cos x}{2-\cos x}$$
be periodic with period $2 \pi$, so that
$$g(x) = \sum_j w_j e^{ijx}$$
where
$$w_j = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} g(x) e^{-ijx} dx$$
Thus,
$$\begin{aligned}
f(x) &= \sum_{k \ge 1} \frac{g(kx)}{k^p} \\
     &= \sum_{k \ge 1} \frac{1}{k^p} \sum_j w_j e^{ijkx} \\
     &= \sum_j w_j \sum_{k \ge 1} \frac{\left(e^{ijx}\right)^k}{k^p} \\
     &= \sum_j w_j \operatorname{Li}_p(e^{ijx})
\end{aligned}$$
You can either approximate the integrals $w_j$ directly or compute a bunch of $f(x)$ values and use a DFT.  In either case, you can potentially apply Richardson extrapolation to the result.  Since in your case $g(x)$ is analytic within a neighborhood of $\mathbb{R}$, the final series converges exponentially even without Richardson.

Comment: I presume you mean $g(x) = \cos(x) / (2 - \cos(x))$?

Answer (score 3):

For $x = 2\pi a/b$ with $a,b$ integer, we have
$$\begin{aligned}
f(x) &= \sum_{k \ge 1} \frac{\cos {kx}}{k^2 (2 - \cos {kx})} \\
   &= \sum_{k=1}^b \frac{\cos {kx}}{2-\cos {kx}} \sum_{n \ge 0} \frac{1}{(k+bn)^2} \\
   &= \sum_{k=1}^b \frac{\cos {kx}}{2-\cos {kx}} \frac{\psi^1(k/b)}{b^2}
\end{aligned}$$
where $\psi^1(z)$ is the trigamma function (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygamma).  Here are plots of the function and its derivative with the artifacts removed:
[image: Values and derivatives for the series]

Comment: Thank you. The problem is that I selected this specific function as a model for another more complicated function that I actually wanted to evaluate, having similar features, but not actually the same. I'm aware of the closed form from [this question on MSE](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/544482/function-fx-int-0-infty-left-sint-cdot-sinx-t-cdot-e-t-right-dt). I meant this as a question about summing an infinite series numerically _without_ closed form.

Comment: Maybe my other answer is better then?

Answer (score 0):

How about the [Levin u-transform](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/6625/levins-u-transformation)? In addition to Fortan codes, there are several versions in the [GSL](http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/): [`gsl_sum_levin_u*'](http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/gsl-ref_30.html). Matlab's [MuPAD](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/mupad_ref/numeric-sum.html) and [Maple](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=evalf/Sum) use this scheme.

Comment: I tried it, but I found Richardson extrapolation to be more accurate.